# In a codenameone project - How can I get images programmatically from the project resources folder?

Tags: codenameone

CodenameOne changed the project structure after the maven dependence manager passed to be used as the new standard for dependence management.

Now exists a new folder called resources at the same level as the java folder. (in project structure)
I put my images inside the /resources/images.

**How can I get these images programmatically?**
I tried some java common approaches without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the images in a folder under resources. Put them directly in `common/src/main/resources` then access them using `/imagename.png` as you always have.